# Vite App in Docker container not accessible on localhost

Tags: docker, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to set up a simple Vite/Vue3 app and run it locally in a Docker container. What I'm trying to accomplish is to simply get Vite to serve up the built files ('vite preview') while running in a container and that I'll be able to pull up on my browser. (This is one discrete bit of a larger issue I'm troubleshooting.) I have the app running in the container on the expected port. But it is inaccessible in the browser.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install`your text
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "preview" ]
```

vite-config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    server: {
        host: true,
        port: 8081
    },
    preview: {
        host: true,
        port: 8081
    }
})
```

package.json

```
`{
    "name": "my-vue-project",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.3.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
        "typescript": "^5.0.2",
        "vite": "^4.4.5",
        "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
    }
}`
```

These are the commands I use to build the image and run the container

```
docker build -t my-image .

docker run -it -p 8081:8080 -d my-image
```

In Docker Desktop, I can see that the app is running
[Docker Desktop logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrtUD.png)

But it can't be reached by the browser (Chrome).
[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mybvi.png)

I have tried reaching it via 'localhost', 'localhost:8081', 'localhost:8080', also by substituting the ip address of the container and the ip address of WSL on my Windows machine for 'localhost'. I have read the relevant discussions I could find on stackoverflow and elsewhere and have not yet found the solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this. The problem has to do with confusion about the container port and the local server port. After changing those all to the same number, the app runs in the container and is accessible in the browser.

Changed lines:
Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 8000
```

vite-config.ts

```
server: {
    host: true,
    port: 8000
},
preview: {
    host: true,
    port: 8000
}
```

run command

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -d my-image
```